# installing an Ember helper through add on then using it in a component breaks the tests

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm installing the 'ember-moment' helper and then I'm using it in components. As soon as I do that, those components' tests break saying pretty much nothing:

```
not ok 120 PhantomJS 1.9 - StatusCardComponent: it renders
---
    actual: >
        null
    message: >
        Died on test #2     at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:2779
            at test (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1796)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/client.js:11190
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:150
            at tryFinally (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:30)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:156
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:29
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:21
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:40
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5545: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'moment' could not be found
    Log: >
...
```

And here is the code of the test itself, it's just the auto generation:

```
import {
  moduleForComponent,
  test
} from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForComponent('event-card', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test
  // needs: ['component:foo', 'helper:bar']
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(2);

  // Creates the component instance
  var component = this.subject();
  assert.equal(component._state, 'preRender');

  // Renders the component to the page
  this.render();
  assert.equal(component._state, 'inDOM');
});
```

I tried a bunch of ways of adding this helper to the test as a dependency  like `needs: ['helper:moment']` and adding its initializer signature to the moduleForComponent function's params, but nothing worked and I can't find any information about it. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can include the code from the test, and what ways you've tried to import it?

Comment: You are going to need a statement like:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: According to this [PR](https://github.com/switchfly/ember-test-helpers/pull/24), you should be able to specify `{ integration: true }` to turn your existing unit test into an integration test, which eliminates the need for `needs:`.

```
 moduleForComponent('post', { integration: true });
```

More background can be found here: https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/issues/108.  Essentially, the integration flag disables the isolated container for the test, so that it has access to the app's resolver.

Note: Requires `ember-qunit@0.2.11.`

**Old Answer**: Take a look at this PR: https://github.com/switchfly/ember-test-helpers/pull/21 which adds `moduleForIntegration`.  Here's the relavant bit:

> This adds a new kind of test module that fills a gap in the current
>   set of possible tests. So far we have:
>
> • unit tests that are good for testing algorithmic correctness in isolation.
>
> • acceptance tests that are good for testing within a complete
>   application.
>
> But we're missing the ability to integration test a unit smaller than
>   whole-application. This PR adds a new  TestModuleForIntegration  that
>   lets you drive an integration test with a template. I think this is
>   often a more appropriate way to test Ember Components than a unit
>   test, because interesting components tend to have rich dependence on
>   other components.

You can see it in use in [liquid-fire tests](https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire/blob/5ee0bf23608e8ea32b162cdc434e12f2a6e8441d/tests/integration/helpers/liquid-if-test.js#L6-L23):

```
/* global sinon */
import Ember from "ember";
import moduleForIntegration from "../../helpers/module-for-integration";
import { test } from "ember-qunit";

moduleForIntegration('Integration: liquid-if');

test('it should render', function(assert) {
  this.set('person', 'Tom');
  this.render(`
    {{#liquid-if isReady}}
      {{person}} is ready
    {{else}}
      {{person}} is not ready
    {{/liquid-if}}
  `); // }}`)

  assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), 'Tom is not ready');
  this.set('person', 'Yehuda');
  assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), 'Yehuda is not ready');
  this.set('isReady', true);
  assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), 'Yehuda is ready');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is what ended up working:

```
import {
    moduleForComponent,
    test
} from 'ember-qunit';

import Ember from 'ember';

import { initialize } from '../../../../../initializers/ember-moment';

moduleForComponent('event-card', {
    // Specify the other units that are required for this test
    // needs: ['helper:moment'],
    setup: function (container) {
        Ember.run(function () {
            // these two arguments are not used
            // but probably still good to pass them in
            // in the event we leverage them in the future
            initialize(container);
        });
    }
});

test('it renders', function (assert) {
    assert.expect(2);

    // Creates the component instance
    var component = this.subject();
    assert.equal(component._state, 'preRender');

    // Renders the component to the page
    this.render();
    assert.equal(component._state, 'inDOM');
});
```

Comment: Worked for me too but my directory reference was: `import { initialize } from '../../../initializers/ember-moment';`

Answer (score 0):

Do you see that line that is commented out that reads:

  `// needs: ['component:foo', 'helper:bar']`

You need to uncomment it out and make it read:

`needs: ['helper:moment']`

That should help, if your `moment` helper is registered correctly